# JSF 2 Mojarra and Primefaces in WebSphere 7+

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, primefaces, mojarra

I have been struggling with the unholy alliance that is WebSphere 7+ and Mojarra 2.0.4 and have run into something of a showstopper.

I followed the directions as specified at this forum post and got Mojarra 2.0.4 initializing properly: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6860

Basically I created an isolated classloader shared library that refers externally to the Mojarra and Primefaces jars, added the shared library to the webapp and reversed the classloader to go PARENT_LAST.  All of that works.

When I attempt to access my web app `http://server:port/context/index.xhtml` it is hitting the FacesServlet correctly but then instantly the Request Dispatcher is redirecting to `index.jsp`???

I don't have any JSP specified ANYWHERE in my code, my app, my web.xml, and in fact I specified `DEFAULT-SUFFIX` to be `.xhtml` and that didn't help.  All my web pages are `.xhtml` extension and FacesServlet is mapped correctly to `*.xhtml`.

I have tried adding XHTML as a mime type to WebSphere, disabling the Request Dispatcher, all to no avail.  I have been able to get this running correctly on Tomcat 6-7, JBoss 6 and Glassfish 3 with no problems but for some reason WebSphere insists on a JSP file extension?

I appreciate any help you might have.

Comment: UPDATE:  Okay I am unable to reproduce this problem with a simple JSF2 HelloWorld application WITHOUT Primefaces.  Either Primefaces or something else is causing this problem.  I am going to start slowly adding things to my hellow world project until it breaks.

Comment: DOUBLE UPDATE: After two unrelated restarts of WebSphere for my test app suddenly the login page comes up for my actual application now, O_o !  Perhaps there were configurations in the `cell` folder that were not propagating correctly?!  Of course now I have a problem where the Primefaces Resources servlet is not serving anything, (Eg. No Primefaces Themes, jQuery, etc...)

Comment: Perhaps you need to register it manually in `web.xml` because the changed classloading does not pick up JAR-packaged `@WebServlet` classes anymore? *Stabbing in the dark* :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAS7 sometimes does not undeploy the web applications properly. Clearing WAS_PROFILE_HOME/temp and WAS_PROFILE_HOME/wstemp may help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is a little too late I am afraid.  We abandoned WebSphere as a possibility a while ago but this answer may still be helpful to others who run into the same problem.

Comment: Good choice: We abandoned WebSphere as a possibility a while ago